# way of doing flexible "INSERT INTO" query with PHP mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay this is going to be a little complex.

But right now i am using a homewritten function to create a query for creating inserting a page into the db.

And i was wondering if there was a smarter way to do a flexible "insert into" method.

The problem is that i have some fields which are optional to type in when creating a page so right now i am using this where i am running through all fields and checks whether they are set or not. :

```
//creates an Array which can be used to make a MySQL query
function createQueryArray($new) {
    if (isset($this->users_id))
        $this->query_array['users_id'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->users_id);
    if (isset($this->pagename))
        $this->query_array['pagename'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->pagename);
    if (isset($this->seo_pagetitle))
        $this->query_array['seo_pagetitle'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->seo_pagetitle);
    if (isset($this->seo_description))
        $this->query_array['seo_description'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->seo_description);
    if (isset($this->seo_keywords))
        $this->query_array['seo_keywords'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->seo_keywords);
    if (isset($this->seo_robots))
        $this->query_array['seo_robots'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->seo_robots);
    if (isset($this->seo_canonical))
        $this->query_array['seo_canonical'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->seo_canonical);
    if (isset($this->type))
        $this->query_array['page_type'] = mysql_real_escape_string($this->type);
    //$this->query_array['last_edited'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Afterwards i am calling this function with the array and the table i wanna insert the page into:

```
function createInsertStm($arr, $table) {
    $mysqlQuery = ("INSERT INTO $table (");
    $insert = "";
    $values = "";
    if (is_array($arr))
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if ($insert == "")
                $insert .= $key;
            else
                $insert .= ', ' . $key;
            if ($values == "")
                $values .= (preg_match('/(MAX\(id\))(.*?)/', $value)) ? $value : '"' . $value . '"';
            else
                $values .= (preg_match('/(MAX\(id\))(.*?)/', $value)) ? "," . $value : ',"' . $value . '"';
        }
    $mysqlQuery .= $insert;
    $mysqlQuery .= ') VALUES (';
    $mysqlQuery .= $values;
    $mysqlQuery .= ')';
    return $mysqlQuery;
}

$db->query($queryArray["pages"]);
```

Is it posible to use a prepared statement and then just skip some of the fields or something similar?

Comment: Take a look at an ORM tool, with an ORM you can focus on your data structures and not the way they are saved. I love Doctrine ORM

Comment: I was reading into the api to the Doctrine 2 yesterday. That sounds pretty cool. But i think it isnt worth to implement it into my little CMS system since it got only one object it wants to store into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a default value in the table definition, then you can omit the value on insert.

Check the following page for more info on default values:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Comment: So @jmack if i have this:
`$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (users_id, pagename, seo_pagetitle, seo_description, seo_keywords, seo_robots, seo_canonical, page_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")`

how wouldt you then bind parameters to it if we say that i dont have values for the last 2 fields?

Comment: You would just omit the two last fields completely. So something like `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (users_id, pagename, seo_pagetitle, seo_description, seo_keywords, seo_robots) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")`

Comment: But then you still have to use a function like createInsertStm($arr, $table) to make the statement. if you sometimes have those last fields som sometimes not